# What word best describes a "living hell"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a word (or a phrase for that matter) to describe a "living hell". The word I am looking for should describe a situation that people would usually want to give up.

To put things in context, here is the sentence where this word would fit.

> Even in this **__** , I find a sense of solace.

**Edit:** Since I am new here at ELU, I didn't realize that my question was that vague. But I want to describe the pain that I went through in the gym and how, despite the pain and the discomfort that I have been through, I have come to love it and how it soothes me. I hope it puts it in some context.

Comment: -1: Use a thesaurus.

http://thesaurus.com/browse/living+hell?s=t

Comment: Not everyone knows **how** to use a thesaurus. Native speakers of English as well as those who aren't well-read native speakers. The OP seems to be more well read than many native speakers, though.

Comment: I don't think your sentence provides sufficient context.  It would be useful to know more about the nature of the "living hell".

Comment: @BillFranke I am a non-native speaker and I can't seem to find an appropriate word from the thesaurus

Comment: @Bidit: As z7sg Ѫ said, "I don't think your sentence provides sufficient context." I agree. We need to know more than you've told us. Can you be more specific? A thesaurus is a good tool if you're familiar enough with all or most of the choices it offers you, but unless you can discriminate between the options provided, it's just a "crap shoot" (a dice game). Give us more info & someone might be able to make an appropriate suggestion for you.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest:

> [***hellhole***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hellhole) :*a place of extreme misery or squalor*

<sub>It's interesting that the thesaurus link given in comments above does not list this as a possibility.</sub>

Comment: That's because it doesn't mean the same thing.

Comment: @Jim: +1 Thesaurus.com isn't a bad thesaurus as far as online thesauruses go. Much better than thefreedictionary.com, I think.  Although it has _hellhole_ in the dictionary module, it's not in the thesaurus module. I think "_a place totally lacking in comfort_" (one of its definitions for _hellhole_) is a good fit for the OP's question, as is "_a place of extreme misery_".

Comment: As Pitarou said, it doesn't mean the same thing. Quoting [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hellhole?s=t) hellhole noun 1. a place totally lacking in comfort, cleanliness, order, etc. 2. a place or establishment noted for its illegal or immoral practices.

Comment: @Danny: I disagree with both of you, who seem unable to get beyond the bald denotations of a dictionary definition, &, perhaps, have never heard the term used to describe anything real. _A place of misery_ can be _a place totally lacking in comfort_ (e.g., a tiger cage in Vietnam: ask John McCain, not me) & _a living hell_. Depression is one kind of living hell, marriage may be another, the DTs (& any other kind of drug withdrawal symptoms) can be a living hell, as can alcohol poisoning. I've been through all of those and other living hells. Why are you so convinced you're right?

Comment: "It's interesting that the thesaurus link given in comments above does not list this as a possibility." -- because this is considered GR.

Comment: @BillFranke a living hell can be a hellhole and a hellhole can be a living hell, however, one does not imply the other. A living hell is an experience. A hellhole is a really dump-of-a/lousy/crappy place. The definition I copied and linked to was only meant as a reference to prove my point.

Comment: Okay, I can appreciate the difference you see -- the terms are always interchangeable -- but living in a hellhole can be a living hell. I imagine John McCain felt that way in Vietnam. OTOH, your definition comes from MW, the same as Pitarou's. That's not the only dictionary in town, & those two definitions aren't the only two ways of expressing _living hell_ & _hell hole_. I didn't create my own definitions. I took them from two different dictionaries. Many of the synonyms for _living hell_ are _hell holes_, and "dump-of-a/lousy/crappy place" is only one possibility for _hell hole_.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you dread most. But you're looking for a vague and general term that includes all types of living hells. Not all the choices in the thesaurus are good ones. Choose the one that suits your ear best. I like these, but others will prefer different words. Strictly a personal choice.

> Agony [sounds good to me with *Even in this* **__**], purgatory, Phlegethon (river of fire in Hades), Gehenna, limbo, perdition.

Answer (score 0):

What about "God-forsaken place"? Sounds exactly opposite to *heaven* as well.

Comment: Not an exact opposite - see my comment to hellhole (they mean the same).